# How to solve Ax = b and Cx = d simultaneously?

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Suppose I have two equations,

$x^TAx +  b^Tx = c$

$x^TBx + d^T x = e$.

How can I express this system as one system and solve it simultaneously?

Thanks!

Comment: The question title conflicts with the body of the question.

Comment: I cannot create a matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix} A & O \\ O & B \end{pmatrix}$ for the quadratic part because M would be $2n \times 2n$, while $x$ is only $n \times 1$.  I was wondering if there was something not so trivial?

Comment: I think I know the answer... form matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix}$, then solve the new system using the new quadratic form $M^TM$, similar to the normal equation approach...